# End of File issues with Prettier formatting for javascript

Tags: lightning-aura-components, formatting, pretty

I've got the following prettier config in my repo. When I commit a `.js`, `.css` file for an aura component, save it to salesforce org, and retrieve it, I find that my git repo complains that something has changed at the end of the file. It's not a regular `endOfLine` character as that would have meant a change in all the lines, but just the end of the file.

Looks like Salesforce and Prettier have a different config for the end of the line and I can't figure out how to fix it. It's annoying that an `ant retrieve` brings up all of my aura components with a different file ending and it's a big `diff` to go through.

I've used various options for `endOfLine` from [here](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#end-of-line), and also tried changing the `apexInsertFinalNewline` from [this](https://github.com/dangmai/prettier-plugin-apex), but no luck.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

My config in `.prettierrc.json`:

```
{
    "printWidth": 100,
    "useTabs": true,
    "trailingComma": "none",
    "bracketSpacing": false,
    "apexInsertFinalNewline": false,
    "overrides": [
        {
            "files": "**/lwc/**/*.html",
            "options": {
                "parser": "lwc"
            }
        },
        {
            "files": "*.{cmp,page,component}",
            "options": {
                "parser": "html"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

[image: Git repo complaining about the end of file]